# Convert double to float by cast or Convert.ToSingle()?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion

In C# I can convert doubles to floats by a cast `(float)` or by `Convert.ToSingle()`.

```
double x = 3.141592653589793238463;
float a = (float)x;
float b = Convert.ToSingle(x);
```

`a` and `b` become equal.

Are there any differences between both techniques? Which one should I prefer and why?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

From the [.NET reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1503):

```
public static float ToSingle(double value)
{
     return (float)value;
}
```

So, your answer is that they are exactly the same, under the hood.

Any preference between the two is strictly a personal style choice. Personally, I would always use the cast as it is shorter and and just seems more idiomatic to me.

Comment: Since there does not seem to be any reason at all to use ToSingle it's not personal choice but objectively better to use a cast.

Comment: The `Convert` class is meant to be the language-neutral way of converting between the different base types of the .NET Framework. Not all languages that run on .NET actually have a cast operator like C#. For example: in VB.NET you have have CType(), CDbl(), DirectCast() and implicit conversion, none of which have the exact same semantics as the cast operator in C#.

Answer (score 1):

While they are exactly the same when casting a `double`, there is a difference if the double has first been cast to an `object`.

```
object x = 1.0;
float a = (float)x;              //InvalidCastException
float b = Convert.ToSingle(x);   //OK
```

The [.NET reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1451) for how it is done is a few lines above the answer provided by @Glorin.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of C#, the Convert methods test whether values ​​are null before converting, and if so, return 0 for primitive numbers. For the same case in an explicit conversion an exception is raised.

An alternative to using a Convert method is to use the ?? operator

```
float floatValue = nullableFloat ?? 0.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted a double to float for a homework assignment using the following:
`{ float squareRoot= (float)Math.Sqrt(input); return squareRoot; }`